# Brakes won't go down as far as usual

Tags: brakes

I had a few situations when I applied my brakes at around 70 km/h, the car wouldn't stop as fast as normal. Normally when I press the brake I would be able to stop much faster (I can feel the car stopping). But this time, the car was slowing down but not as fast as it should be.

As for the brakes, I felt like it wouldn't go down far enough. As an analogy, if my car was off and I pressed the brakes, it would go down a bit then it would be stopped. That is what is felt like. It felt like something was stopping the brakes from going down further.

I am really confused about this situation and this is 3rd time this has happened. Any help is appreciated thx.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! What is the year/make/model/engine of the vehicle in question?

Comment: Have you looked around the pedal to make sure nothing is getting in the way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From what you describe it sounds as though perhaps the brake servo/booster isn't working properly giving you a hard pedal feeling, this could be due to a fault with the servo/booster itself or the brake master  cylinder. Vacuum leaks in servo hoses etc can also cause such issues
Please have this checked out ASAP, it is important that any brake faults/issues are rectified quickly.